# how to persist object on db at the right time in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm workin on symofony2 doctrine project.

Actually I've  a problem with  persisting object if there is some errors during it's edit.

I fetch existing obj from the db in the "traditional way":

```
 $event=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('LapoCalendarBundle:Event')->find($id);
```

then I try to edit it with some conditional operation that could terminate with a command like:

```
$event->setDescription($description);
```

These operation are conditional and excuted one by one, so if for example the second control before a next set operation fail for some reason the `$description` field setted before is anyway allready on the db, before any explict call of the:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
               $em->persist($event);
               $em->flush();
```

so my question is: there is a way for editing obj and persist it just at the time that we expect? or exist a revert command on symofny2 or doctrine/orm?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from flushing only at the end of execution?  If you don't flush, persisted entities won't be written.

Comment: sorry @Flosculus but this isn't true...if the object is allready from your db the the exe or do not exe flush do not change anything...if set something this will be on the db too

Comment: `persist` only needs to be called on newly created entities.  Otherwise all entities from the DB are already managed by doctrine, so flushing after change will take effect.  But flush does need to be called to write to the DB.

Comment: @Flosculus sorry I can't understand you, you say that flush() is just for new entities, but if you call it on some obj allready on the db it will take effect anyway... so is just for the new one or even for the old db istance

Comment: I said  `persist` needs to be called for new entities. Its better if you read up on it: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html, look specifically at persisting and detaching.

Comment: @Flosculus yes i read on it some time ago but no solution to my prob, sorry but eng is not my native lang...I found this  [http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html)  more usefull but actually ive an error that i cant recognize...

Answer (score 0):

```
$em->refresh($event);
```

Will reset/revert the entity object to it's original values.

Comment: yes I willy try, I found even this approach:  `$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // suspend auto-commit
try {
    //... do some work
    $user = new User;
    $user->setName('George');
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $em->getConnection()->rollback();
    $em->close();
    throw $e;
}` but actually dint work to me... an error like: "There is no active transaction. " is raised every time...

Comment: the solution from @Cerad doesn't work to me: `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
               $em->refresh($event);
               $em->flush();`                                                               persist what was set by operetion like setDescription($event) done before

Comment: Nope.  You got something else going on.  Setup a little test command and spend some time learning how the system works.

Comment: ok so flus() must be called once time for method and best at the end or is it a wrong supposition?

Answer (score 0):

I've read carefully the symofny2 and doctrine guide again and what maybe i've missing from before is how object allready persited are treated...

But in best pratice or in other section i didn't find an answer to some basic question:

-if Ive a method A that call C and D and i've different "setSomething()" operation, where i've to call the flush method? 
- in each method
-just at the end of the main A

And if Persist($obj) is just for new istance never persisted yet, then is an error call it anyway over a pre-persisted object?
For example if I've A method can be generate a new one $obj or raise up an old one (depending from some condition) but ive same operation to do over both...

ex:

```
if(a) { $event=oldboj;} else $event= new Obj();
.....DOING SOMETHING ON $event->setAAAA('ooo');
.......
some error-->$em->refresh($event); return error; else go ahead....
......
em->persist($event);
em->flush;
.....
```

could be a right approach to the problem?